# multiplying gamma function over different input variables

Tags: calculus, gamma-function

I have a function (the Gamma function) defined as:

$$
F(\alpha) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}dx
$$

Now, I want to multiply this function evaluated at two points as:

$$
F(\alpha_0) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha_0-1} e^{-x}dx
$$

and 
$$
F(\alpha_1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{\alpha_1-1} e^{-x}dx
$$

Is there a way to get an integral expression in terms of the original gamma function? So, basically can I say something like

$$
F(\alpha_0) F(\alpha_1) = F(\alpha_0 + \alpha_1)
$$

or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One intuition on the $\Gamma$ function is the identity $$\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$$ for integer $n \geq 1$. It is certainly easy to see that
$$
n! \times m! \neq (n+m)!
$$

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I have a follow up question but I will ask that in a new thread